# RxSwift Subscribe onNext not called after bind

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I am using RxSwift 4.0 and build tableView content using `DTTableViewManager`

in Presenter, I have model variable

**1**

```
lazy var mostRecent: TableTitleHeaderContainer = {
    let container = TableTitleHeaderContainer(isHidden: true, title: "Title 1")
    return container
}()

lazy var lastRecent: TableTitleHeaderContainer = {
    let container = TableTitleHeaderContainer(isHidden: false, title: "Title 2")
    return container
}()
```

code of model

**2**

```
class TableTitleHeaderContainer {
    var subject: PublishSubject<Void> = PublishSubject<Void>()
    var isHidden: Bool
    var title: String
    var disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    init(isHidden: Bool, title: String) {
        self.isHidden = false
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

and view configuration with model

**3**

```
extension TableTitleHeaderView: ModelTransfer {
    func update(with model: TableTitleHeaderContainer) {
        clearButton.isHidden = model.isHidden
        clearButton.rx.tap
            .bind(to: model.subject).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        titleLabel.text = model.title
    }
}
```

And I want to listen tap on button in Presenter

**4**

```
mostRecent.subject.asObserver().subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (_) in
    print("Clear mostRecent")
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)

lastRecent().subject.asObserver().subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (_) in
    print("Clear lastRecent")
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

But after configure view with model subscribe in Presenter does not call?
What is the trouble?

Comment: Have you tried adding `.debug()` to `subject`? Your stream might be disposed before `onNext` event. How and when do you initialize `disposeBag` in `TableTitleHeaderView`?

Comment: @Jeremy property  `var disposeBag = DisposeBag()`